# templates accepting two iterators

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

Why ordinary algorithm template is designed so that it accepts two iterators instead of pair of these iterators ? Consider this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <typename Range, typename OutputIterator> 
void copy2 (Range r, OutputIterator o) {
     copy (r.first, r.second, o);
}

template <typename iter1, typename iter2> 
pair<typename iter1, typename iter2> Range(iter1 start, iter2 end) {
    return make_pair(start, end);
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> myvector;
    myvector.push_back(3);
    myvector.push_back(2);
    myvector.push_back(1);

    // ordinary algorithm template accepts two iterators
    copy(myvector.begin(), 
         myvector.end(), 
         ostream_iterator<int> (cout,"\n") );

    // this template accepts iterator Range
    copy2(Range(myvector.begin(),myvector.end()),
          ostream_iterator<int> (cout,"\n"));
}
```

What are reasons of copy() being better than copy2() [**other than copy2() call verbosity**]

**EDIT:** I cut down verbosity of copy2() by a great amount as DeadMG suggested.

Comment: What is the benefit of wrapping the iterators into a pair?  All I see is that it requires more typing and a dependency on the pair type.

Comment: Isn't the verbosity of copy2() a good enough reason?

Comment: @Joe: That's true, but that can be solved easily with a little imagination.

Comment: Range based algorithms were under discussion for C++0x, but not included in the final draft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really? There isn't one. The Standard library only has the notion of iterators because, as far as I know, nobody came up with ranges before it was Standardised. Many people think that it could be vastly improved by using ranges. Secondly, you can easily improve the verbosity of #2 with a little extra pre-written boiler.

```
template<typename T> std::pair<typename T::const_iterator, typename T::const_iterator> all(const T& t) {
    return std::make_pair(t.begin(), t.end());
}
template<typename T> std::pair<typename T::iterator, typename T::iterator> all( T& t) {
    return std::make_pair(t.begin(), t.end());
}

copy2(all(myvector), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, "\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I look at it as keeping things simple.  What does wrapping your iterators in another container give you, other than a smaller signature for your copy2 function?  (Personally, I don't see any advantage to wrapping it in a pair, so it is just more code to write to call the function)

And looking at the example code you posted, the original copy call is (IMO) much more readable than the copy2 call.

Comment: It is, but it can be made much cleaner with a little imagination.

Comment: True, but why?  More code (even adding unnecessary typedefs) opens the door to more errors.  function(container.begin(), container.end()) is already clear, and for general programming, I don't see any point in wrapping it in a "range" object.  Think of when you start having reverse iterators on top of your forward iterators.. more typedefs to create.  (sure, there are specific cases where a range might be nice, and in those cases, one has the ability to code up a wrapper function like the OPs copy2, but I'd say this is the exception and not the norm)

Comment: Dealing with all a container is the norm. Dealing with ranges is by far and away more common than dealing with iterators. If dealing with ranges was optimized, there would be a significant benefit for everyone.

Comment: Just to add something- "with a little imagination" is IMHO, means to me, "this should only be done if necessary."  It is one thing if  you have a critical algorithm that can be sped up through some imagination (and includes good commenting/documentation), but for something as simple as passing iterators?  First, I don't want to fall back on my imagination to figure out what I was doing, and second, I definitely don't want some other programmer working on my code to need to figure out my imagination.

Comment: @DeadMG- In C++ I'd argue that dealing with iterators is much more common, and most proficient C++ coders will be  comfortable seeing calls to container algorithms using iterators rather than ranges.  As I tried to say before- its not that you shouldn't do these things, it is that you should have a good reason to do them.  "Ranges is how these things are dealt with in other languages" isn't a good reason in my book (though that doesn't prevent it from being a good reason in yours) :)

Comment: A little imagination means that it took about two generic programming brain cells to write six lines that serve an obvious function with a good name. This isn't about speed, it's about being clear, and I think that `copy(all(container), iterator)` is much clearer than `copy(container.begin(), container.end(), iterator)`. In C++ dealing with iterators directly is much more common- because the library doesn't offer ranges. I meant more semantically, iterators are most often used in pairs. And I never even stated that other languages use ranges. Ranges are vastly clearer than iterators.

Comment: Fair enough (I do see how the all range would be nice to have).  Any thoughts on how your idea changes when moving to a subset of the entire container?  It seems that once you start specifying subsets, a set of iterators is about the same as constructing a range object.  (Also, I work with a few programmers who don't have even 2 generic programming brain cells, so I tend to be careful about these things).

Comment: That's fair enough, most people are, let's face it, significantly less smart than me :). The difference between iterators and ranges is that yes, if you want to specify a range which isn't all of them, then it's two iterators again. But that's only at the construction site- after that, it's just another range. Whereas two iterators, you'd have to deal with two iterators *everywhere*. For example, *every* Standard function that takes pairs of iterators could be reduced like this- but you'd only pay to construct a non-all range once.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's so that if you already have single iterators you don't have to construct a pair to call the algorithm, and that it keeps all the arguments to the algorithm consistent: An iterator of some sort (and possibly a predicate).

Comment: But what if you already have a pair and could pass only reference to it ?

Answer (score 0):

In `copy2` there's a little extra overhead from having to construct the pair from your two iterators.  It may not be much but there's no reason to add extra computations if they're not necessary.

Also, the benefits of keeping code as easy to understand as possible shouldn't be underestimated.